# Import operation for "database name" failed. Error code undefined

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have uploaded databases bacpac files on Azure blob storage. When I am importing the databases in SQL Azure, I am facing issue as

> Import operation for {my-database-name} failed. Error-code : undefined Error Message:Failed.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what's going on.

I have created the SQL Server admin user with user name as **"xyz"**.

This user is already existed in my SQL server database in ".backpack" files. When I provided new SQL Server admin, import process succeeded.

This error may also happen due to incorrect credentials of SQL Server admin.